# How to play individual albums in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I know of two ways to play one specific album in iTunes:

- Do a search that's specific enough to include just that album and no other tracks; press a "Play album" button. (Doesn't work in cover flow or list view.)
- Go to list view; turn on column browser; in View/Column Browser, make sure "Albums" is showing; double-click an album name.

These are fine as far as they go, but:

- Double-clicking an album in cover flow will play the album, and then keep going (in alphabetical order). That's no good.
- In playlists like "Purchased" or "Recently Added", you can either view and play whole albums, or sort by date added; you can't do both.
- In general, there's no straightforward way to get from a track in a playlist to the whole album it belongs to.

What I would really, really like, would be to right-click on any song or album cover, anywhere, and choose "Play album".

While I'm waiting for Apple to add that, any tips for simple album-centric listening?

Answer (score 1):

if you switch to grid view then goto Menu Bar => View => Grid View => Album 
then you can view individual albums and use them like a playlist for specific album 
if the music you are playing has the track numbers entered in the tags then these should be sorted by track number by default unless you have the track list sorted by song name 
hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is to hold the <kbd>alt</kbd> key while clicking the "ping" button (<kbd>alt</kbd>+Click) on the row of the desired artist/album.

This will bring up a small menu in which you can select to show the album or artist in it's own listing.